# UISplitViewController change master and details view form details view

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have implemented UISSplitViewController with a master and detail view as per the documentation.  I would like to select an item from the tableview (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) in the current details view, then switch the master view (rootviewController ) with the current detail view and switch in a new detail view.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the views managed by UISplitViewController using the `viewControllers` property.

The official docs are here.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_4

`viewControllers` returns an array of views.  The zero-index element should be the left view, the one-index element should be the right view.